# Secret Menu in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I know there is a secret dev menu in Chrome that you can enable "beta" features, but I forgot where it is. I know that this menu has the option to hold cmd/ctrl+q to quit and thats what I want it for. It also has options for preloading links on the page while you wait and stuff like that.

Any help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think `about:flags` is what you're looking for.

Comment: THANK YOU! I couldnt take one more time of missing cmd+w and hitting cmd+q

Comment: @Oscar, that page is not really an “easter egg”, in fact it’s listed in `about:about`. And what option are you referring to regarding the hotkey? I cannot find anything that can do that.

Comment: Maybe its only a Mac feature? But there is an option called "confirm to quit" which will make it so you have to hold cmd+q for a full second to quit.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not really technically an easter egg, but it is for someone who isn't a dev as about:about is still more of a developer centric page.